# Org-mode epigraph?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I wanted to have a block of text aligned to the right, which takes up less horizontal space then the rest of the text on that page. How'd I go about it?

The problem with it being completed in literal HTML is that org-mode automatically puts any text outside the sections into a `<p>` tag (and it is not a block element, so floating inside of it isn't generally a good thing etc.)

Here's how I have it now (and it displays fine, so I'd like it to be more or less like that):

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<div style="width:100%;height:84pt">
<p class="epigraph">
<em>
I have not increased nor diminished the measure,<br/>
I have not diminished the palm,<br/>
I have not encroached upon fields,<br/>
I have not added to the balance weights,<br/>
I have not tempered with the plumb bob of the balance.</em>
<br/>
<span style="text-align:right;width:100%;display:block">
<b style="line-height:24pt;font-weight:bold">
The Book of the Dead, Spell 125.</b>
</span>
</p></div>
#+END_HTML
```

Plus I have this CSS:

```
.epigraph {
    float:right;
    font-size:10pt;
    font-family:serif;
    line-height:12pt;
    color: #aaa
}
```

But I'd rather it be automatic...

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I found something that worked similar enough to what I wanted:

```
#+BEGIN_VERSE
I have not increased nor diminished the measure,
I have not diminished the palm,
I have not encroached upon fields,
I have not added to the balance weights,
I have not tempered with the plumb bob of the balance.
          -- The Book of the Dead, Spell 125.
#+END_VERSE
```

This generates HTML that later with some use of CSS is possible to format in the way it would look more or less like an epigraph. Not perfect, but will do.